# get an interface with only the unique fileds included

Tags: typescript, nestjs, prisma

in the prisma we have some model

```
model User {
  id       String @id @unique @default(uuid()) @db.Uuid
  email    String @unique
  password String
}
```

and prisma orm generate interface for it

```
type User = {
    id: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
}
```

so the question is can I somehow, someway get the interface with only unique fields from prisma

```
interface IUserWihOnlyUniqueFields {
  id: string;
  password: string;
}
```